# how do i autostart batch file on windows startup

Tags: batch-file, cmd, autostart

I would like my batch script to start automatically when my victim starts their computer. But it does not work when I put the file under "Start Menu".
So how do I do?

Comment: The word *victim* looks suspicious...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the batch script (or a `.lnk` shortcut to it) under (for a specific user)

```
%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

or (for all users, putting it here may require Admin privilege)

```
%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

Or you can edit the registry to add an item or use Windows Task Scheduler. These two methods allow you to put your batch script anywhere.

FYI, I used to [deploy my script](https://github.com/iBug/Vira-2/blob/cb3056232f9a1ebf078281b4c0ccf551b530a791/Vira_2.vbs#L341-L342)<sup>1</sup> by putting it somewhere and adding an entry (the type should be `REG_SZ`) under this registry key:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

(replace HKLM with HKCU to add an item for a specific user instead of all users)

<sub>1: Link goes to my GitHub repo</sub>

Comment: BTW `shell:startup` can be used to get to the first location (user specific)